# cleartext traffic permitted xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

this is mine Network security config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<network-security-config>
  <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
</configuration>
```

this is mine Android.manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.syncfusion.xamarin.uikit" android:installLocation="internalOnly">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />      
  <application android:label="APOP" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" > 
  </application> 
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
</manifest>
```

Application is running fine but when I have to deploy that apk to Google play it says you need to have only 1 application tag !
So I did this change

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.syncfusion.xamarin.uikit" android:installLocation="internalOnly">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />    
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:label="APOP" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" />
</manifest>
```

However this is causing application to crash ! I am not sure why it says "failed to parse Network security config.xaml" file ! Even though I have this file inside resources->xml->filename.

Comment: compare yours to the samples here - none of them have the `configuration` tag - https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

Comment: thanks it is working !

Comment: The Network Security Configuration feature uses an XML file where specifying the settings for the app. We must include an entry in the manifest of your app to point to this file.

Comment: please check this :
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/cleartext-http-android-network-security/